# Designing in landscape with Storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, storyboard

Is it possible to design interfaces in landscape with Interface Builder? Others with the same question apparently were able to do so with an arrow at the top right of any selected view, but I see no such arrow. A picture would be helpful. (Note: I am using storyboards, not xibs.)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Select the window in the storyboard, and open its Simulated Metrics property page (upper-right corner, an icon that looks like a shield next to the ruler icon). If the Simulated Metrics group is collapsed, expand it by clicking the black triangle to its left. There you will find an Orientation property; set it to `Landscape`.

Comment: This is old and not valid anymore. A related function is at bottom of the main IB view.

Answer (score 83):

The answer is correct, but I like a visual:

[image]

Comment: You should click on black bar below the view, otherwise you will select the UIView instead of UIViewController (or other Controller) - for Xcode 5, 100% scale at least

Comment: Remember to expand the Simulated Metrics group. (I've been tripped up in Xcode 5 where it's not immediately obvious a group is collapsed.)

Comment: You have have Size->"Inferred" AND Orientation->"Landscape" checked in Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: Well I have no trouble finding "Orientation" and "Size" and setting them to "Landscape" and "Inferred".  The trouble is that when I do that the storyboard image display doesn't spin or re-proportion itself to the Landscape aspect ratio.

Comment: This is old and not valid anymore. A related function is at bottom of the main IB view.

Answer (score 11):

The answers above got me the answer, but I needed another step in Xcode 5.  Instead of just clicking on my GLKView, I needed to select the GLKit View Controller property below the view.  Then the Orientation appeared in the Attributes Inspector.

[image: GLKView attributes]

Comment: This is old and not valid anymore. A related function is at bottom of the main IB view.

Answer (score 7):

For Xcode 8 - Click the `View As` text at the bottom of the storyboard:

[image: Storyboard to landscape]

Answer (score 0):

**Latest(2023)**: `XCode 12+` There is an orientation button at bottom of Storyboard inspector.
Picture for refence.
[p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I04jm.png)
[p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9ABt.png)