# How to design ui in both portrait and landscape in ios5 using storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5, storyboard, landscape-portrait

How to design ui in both portrait and landscape in interface builder in iphone or ipad (Iam using storyboard not xib..)..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If possible link any examples you have..

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599195/designing-in-landscape-with-storyboards ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want design UI using storyboard, In latest iOS version there is option of Out Layout.

Using Autolayout you can manage UI for both modes.

Hope this will help you

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Or

Other alternate provided on

[iPhone Storyboard: different scene for portrait and landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777629/iphone-storyboard-different-scene-for-portrait-and-landscape)

When you add a view controller to the storyboard it comes with a view. Call that the container view. Add two views to the container view: a portrait view and a landscape view. Set the dimension of the portrait view and the landscape view appropriately using the size inspector. Add buttons, more views, labels or whatever to the portrait and landscape views as needed for your application. Then when the orientation changes hide one view and show the other.

Hope this will help you out.